# Java path for two JDK versions and two users in same windows machine?

Tags: java, windows

I am trying to use two different JDK versions JDK1.7 and JDK1.8 for two different users in a Windows machine. But I am getting the same version for both the users.  How do I get different versions for different users permanently.

If I set in command prompt I get the different versions, but how do I make it permanently without setting path in command prompt like `set path=%path%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin;.;` for one user and for another user like `setpath=%path%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin;.;...`.

**JAVA PATH:**

[image: JAVA PATH]

Answer (score 0):

`JAVA_PATH` is part of the environment variables. There are two kinds of these variables: systemwide environment variables and user environment variables. Systemwide means that these variables are specified for all users. The user-kind on the other hand is only used by the user they are specified for.

So instead of setting `JAVA_PATH` systemwide simply set it for each user as appropriate and each user should use it's own version of the JDK. Though Java is backward compatible, so you could just aswell use JDK8 for both users.

Comment: Hi Paul, I tried to set User Variables only.... But the problem here is it is by default taking JDK1.8 only in both users. Is there any default configuration in JDK1.8 to take that version in both Users.

Answer (score 0):

Create Environment variables -> "User Variable" pointing to different [Java]/bin for different users. One with java 7 & other with Java 8.

Comment: Hi Dinil, I tried to set User Variables only.... But the problem here is it is by default taking JDK1.8 only in both users.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `PATH` environment variable in user variables section of `Environment Variables` for respective user.Then you will be able to use different version for different user.

[image]

Comment: Hi Anand Mishra, I tried to set User Variables only.... But the problem here is it is by default taking JDK1.8 only in both users.

Comment: @vijayD  First remove the path of JDK 1.8 from both user and one by one add the path for both user by login that user. Also check in System variable path if there JDK1.8 path is included remove it.

Comment: JDK 1.7 is not excuting the javac without setting path like (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin;.;) But here after installing JDK 1.8 by default it is taking JDK 1.8 in both users.  I am doing the procedure from the beginning as you told now.

Comment: @vijayD Delete C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath and again set environment variable.

Comment: JDK 1.8 By default it creating (C:\Program Data\Oracle\java\javapath) after removing the path also it is taking by default JDK 1.8.. I is to checked in the registry files  and removed the 1.8  key entry from the registry then also it is taking JDK 1.8 only...